# How can I align CENTER (Horizontal Top) the content in the highlighted columns?

Tags: latex

I am new to latex and stuck in the formatting and alignment of the table. I have also attached a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

CODE:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begingroup
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\linespread{1.2}  %   this decrease the vertical spacing between lines
\rmfamily        %   without this, \linespread doesn't give expected effect
\caption{Datasets used in our study, (1 Gbyte = 10\textsuperscript{9} bytes)}

    \begin{tabular}{ p{0.7em}  p{7.5em} p{2.3em}  p{2em} p{2em}  p{18em} | p{2em}  p{2em} p{2em}  p{18em} } \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{SN} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tools (version; \\ compression type)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{k = 28}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{k = 55}} \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
        &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Time\\ (s)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}RAM\\ (GB)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Disk\\ (GB)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}CPU utilization (\%) \\ (comment)\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Time\\ (s)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}RAM\\ (GB)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Disk\\ (GB)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}CPU utilization (\%) \\ (comment)\end{tabular}\\ \hline

    1 & Jellyfish (2.2.6) & 138.33 & 7.9 & 0 & 1093.55 (consistent) & 226 & \textit{\textbf{36.19}} & 0 & \textbf{1050.93* (consistent)} \\ 
    2 & DSK (2.2.0) & 56.33 & 6.35 & 6 & 866.50 (consistent) & 78.33 & 7.04 & 5 & 633.49 (declined from $\sim$1174 to $\sim$129.7) \\ 
    3 & DSK (2.2.0; gzip) & 194 & 4 & 6 & 402.71(first 80\% of time consistent  with $\sim$300; last 20\% inconsistent to $\sim$1200 with sudden increase) & 222 & 6 & 5 & 441.21 (first 75\% of time consistent with $\sim$390; last 25\% inconsistent to $\sim$1200 with sudden increase) \\ 

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\endgroup
\end{landscape}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) package. It defines a new column type S that aligns numbers on their decimal point.

The package was completely perturbed by your overly complex table, with many nested tables in it. In general, you should never need to do that. I have rewritten your table in a much simpler and more readable way.

Note that an S column *needs* to have a numeric entry. If you have some text (for instance in a header), you can

- redefine the type of the cell to c (or l, p, etc) `\multicolumn{1}{c}{text entry}`
- or simply enclose your entry in braces {text entry}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begingroup
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\linespread{1.2}  %   this decrease the vertical spacing between lines
\rmfamily        %   without this, \linespread doesn't give expected effect
\caption{Datasets used in our study, (1 Gbyte = 10\textsuperscript{9} bytes)}


\begin{tabular}{ p{0.7em}  p{7.5em} SSS  p{18em} | SSS  p{18em} }
      \hline
      \multirow{2}{*}{SN} &Tools (version; &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{k = 28}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{k = 55}} \\
      \cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
                          &compression&{Time}& {RAM}& {Disk}&{CPU utilization (\%)}&{Time}& {RAM}&{Disk}&{CPU utilization (\%)}\\
                          & type)     &{(s)} &{(GB)}&{(GB)} &{(comment)}           &{(s)} &{(GB)}&{(GB)}&{(comment)}\\
      \hline
    1 & Jellyfish (2.2.6) & 138.33 & 7.9 & 0 & 1093.55 (consistent) & 226 & \textit{\textbf{36.19}} & 0 & \textbf{1050.93* (consistent)} \\ 
    2 & DSK (2.2.0) & 56.33 & 6.35 & 6 & 866.50 (consistent) & 78.33 & 7.04 & 5 & 633.49 (declined from $\sim$1174 to $\sim$129.7) \\ 
    3 & DSK (2.2.0; gzip) & 194 & 4 & 6 & 402.71(first 80\% of time consistent  with $\sim$300; last 20\% inconsistent to $\sim$1200 with sudden increase) & 222 & 6 & 5 & 441.21 (first 75\% of time consistent with $\sim$390; last 25\% inconsistent to $\sim$1200 with sudden increase) \\ 

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\endgroup
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Alian Thank you for a solution and for the simplified code. I tried it, but still those entries are not center aligned(top). Could you please provide me some more pointers on the same. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by " center aligned(top)". What does the `S` option is to center the decimal point which is generally what is required. Looking at the table, I realize that the "disk" columns do not have decimal point and the column specifier should be replaced by "c" to center the numbers. Besides that, I woud suggest you to look at the [siunitx documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf). Pages  44-58, there are *many* options to finely control the number alignments, illustrated with examples.